# How to load local javascript file into DOM using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a javascript file which works fine in HTML page written inside script tag, but at the same time when I try to read the file and load using webdriver it is showing some exception.
Below is my code.

```
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            lines = Files.readLines(fileEntry, Charset.defaultCharset());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String line : lines) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            if (!fileEntry.getName().endsWith(".js")) {
                continue;
            }
            JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            String script =
                "var scriptElt = document.createElement('script');"
                    + "scriptElt.type = 'text/javascript';"
                    + "scriptElt.innerHtml = " + sb.toString() + ";"
                    + "document.body.appendChild(scriptElt);";
            je.executeScript(script);`
```

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ";"

Comment: what is in the file you read in? And as my ByteHamster did already, I would suggest you tell us the stack trace.

Comment: Where as the same working when I use the same js file for sample html page

Comment: It is simple .js file. I used it in HTML like <script src = "myFile.js"</script>. I tried even writing the content of the file like <script>content </script>. It works in both cases. But not when loading from WEBDRIVER

Comment: Is there something wrong the way I read the JS file ? I am assuming the blank spaces or new lines.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the quotes. Additionally, if there are quotes in the file, it will result in an error. This line:

```
+ "scriptElt.innerHtml = " + sb.toString() + ";"
```

It should be something like this:

```
+ "scriptElt.innerHtml = '" + sb.toString().replace("'","\\'") + "';"
```

Comment: I added the quotes, but my js file has something like this : `'<iframe frameborder="0" tabindex="-1"`. Which is the combination of both quotes. Above solution is not working.

Comment: My code example also replaces quotes with `\'`. Should also work with the code you posted. Are there any new error messages?